# Set a dynamic property in ngModel inside ngFor, with Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a component with :

- "selectedData" : any
- "fields" : An array of fields. A field is an object with these properties : label and type. These fields describe the object "selectedData"

**Example** :

```
selectedData = { Label:"test", IsUsed:false}

fields = [{name:'label', type:'string'},{name:'IsUsed, type:'boolean'}
```

I am trying to generate a form for editing the data inside 'selectedData'

Here is the part of my view :

```
 <div class="ui-grid-row" *ngFor="let myField of fields" >
            <div class="ui-grid-col-4"><label for="{{myField.name}}">{{myField.name}}</label></div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-8"><input pInputText id="{{myField.name}}" [(ngModel)]="this['selectedData.' + myField.name]" /></div>
        </div>
```

The problem is with this line

```
[(ngModel)]="this['selectedData.' + myField.name]"
```

It does not work as I wanted.
Here is the Google Chrome watch of my component when i edit :
[image: screen capture of my problem]

As you can see, Angular2 creates an object with name "selectedData.Label" instead of using the selectedData existing object.

Is there a solution? Or should I do it differently?

Thx

Comment: I have a really difficult time understanding this. So you are trying in your example to edit the label of existing selectedData. Then it should be e.g `[(ngModel)]="selectedData.Label"` otherwise it won't update the label.

Comment: for what purpose do you need the fields array?

Comment: The purpose is to edit the fields, without knowing at design time the name of the field.
"Label" is just an exemple. I would like to be able to use my form for any object, having only the fields definitions

Comment: Oh, okay. Now I understand what you mean!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was easy :

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedData[myField.name]"
```

If field.Name has a value of 'label', the previous code is equivalent as :

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedData.label"
```

I did not know that the '[ ]' could be used this way.

Comment: I can't understand your answer. Please explain a little bit more.

Comment: @Sylvain Reverdy but how we can capture data with proper key in component then..

Comment: How to populate at .ts side ?