# How to set default checked value for RadioButton in Angular using *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am iterating over list of radio button based on the length of an array and wanted to set checked as default value for only first element/input field

How can i set only one field as checked and remaining other be unchecked?

I am using *ngFor to iterate over items
ngModel for two way data binding

```
<div class="pt-3 flex flex-nowrap">
  <div *ngFor="let color of colors" class="mr-2">
    <input id="{{color}}" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="getColor" value="{{color}}"  [defaultChecked]="getChecked()" name="radio" class="hidden" />
    <label class="mr-2 items-center flex border-2 border-white" for="{{color}}">
      <div class="h-5 w-5 bg-{{color}}-500 m-0.5"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my Component

```
export class AppComponent {
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
getColor = 'gray';
private isChecked = false;

getChecked(): boolean {
  if (!this.isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = true;
    return this.isChecked;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: [checked]="indexOfElement == 0"  but still not working..

Answer (score 1):

After so many research finally I found the answer.
Because here I am using two way data binding (ngModel) we need to set default value for associated selector.

[(ngModel)]='selectedColor'

```
<div *ngFor="let color of colors" class="mr-2">
  <input 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" 
    id="{{color}}" type="radio"
    value="{{color}}"
    name="radio"
    class="hidden" />
 </div>
```

.ts component

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple'];
selectedColor = this.colors[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

***ngFor** provide **index** and based on that index you can have default select like below:

```
<div class="pt-3 flex flex-nowrap">
  <div *ngFor="let color of colors; let idx = index" class="mr-2">
    <input id="{{color}}" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="getColor" [checked]="(idx === 0)" value="{{color}}" name="radio" class="hidden" />
    <label class="mr-2 items-center flex border-2 border-white" for="{{color}}">
      <div class="h-5 w-5 bg-{{color}}-500 m-0.5"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working when not applied ngModel but when i applied ngModel its not working. What replacement should i do for ngModel

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try,

remove *defaultChecked* attribute because we need to use **checked** attribute here.

```
<div class="pt-3 flex flex-nowrap">
  <div *ngFor="let color of colors; let i = index" class="mr-2">
    <input id="{{color}}" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="getColor" value="{{color}}"  [checked]="i == 0" name="radio" class="hidden" />
    <label class="mr-2 items-center flex border-2 border-white" for="{{color}}">
      <div class="h-5 w-5 bg-{{color}}-500 m-0.5"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try to remove *ngModel* (if not required to capture input data) or use dynamic *ngModel* implementation for **ngFor** like below

- [Set a dynamic property in ngModel inside ngFor, with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308067/set-a-dynamic-property-in-ngmodel-inside-ngfor-with-angular-2)

Comment: agree with your point but still not checked my first input can you review my code.. whats wrong with it? –

Comment: its working when not applied ngModel but when i applied ngModel its not working

Comment: okay, that's because of you are using same ngModel for all the input fields so..

Comment: @nirazv, updated the answer please check. In another way you can also use click event with input and capture the data from there..

Answer (score 0):

1. the checked property of the desired checkbox should be declared by default in [your.component.ts]
2. in the template use the checked attribute

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kyf3bo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)