# Angular - Dynamic ngModel for inputs

Tags: angular

How can I have a dynamic model for a form element (i.e. input, select)?

I have this:

```
<input type="text" [name]="input.name" [(ngModel)]="input.name" [title]="input.title" />
```

wherein the model could be anything (i.e. address, first_name) as it is generated dynamically?

```
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

    inputs!:any[];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        console.log(this.inputs);

    }

}
```

I looked for relevant questions this one being the closest [Set a dynamic property in ngModel inside ngFor, with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308067/set-a-dynamic-property-in-ngmodel-inside-ngfor-with-angular-2), but I can seem to do the trick. Is there another way to achieve this?

Angular version: (12.0.2)

Thanks in advance!`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

You would be much better off using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead of [Template Driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms) forms to achieve this task, since it gives you more flexibility, ease of use when it comes to dynamic validators and multiple working examples (including [this one](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) on the official docs).

Since your model has `any` type, this pretty much answers your question - no need to repeat the official docs in my opinion (though there are multiple other valid examples if you google ["angular dynamic form"](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular%20dynamic%20form).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this, I've already migrated it however, the problem that I am still encountering is how to make a dynamic FormControlName. Do you think it would be better to ask a new question as this seems to be a separate topic?

Comment: The linked article from official docs covers just that. Take a look at the [Compose dynamic form contents](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#compose-dynamic-form-contents) section. It covers binding of the `formControlName`, e.g. `[formControlName]="question.key"`

Comment: Yes, I already did that and it worked! Thanks. I have a weird problem, the template is not being rendered when I add that directive in one of the inputs. I don't think this is async problem because it was working when I use a different value for the [formControlName]

Comment: I think it would be best if you reproduced your new issue in stackblitz and posted this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#I guess you might look at this
https://angular.io/guide/forms#bind-input-controls-to-data-properties

#import FormsModule

#create a template driven form
<form #myForm="ngForm">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
               required
               [(ngModel)]="input.name" name="input.name"
[title]="input.title"
               #name="ngModel">
<!-- for example -->
<select class="form-control" id="cities"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="model.city" name="cities"
                #cities="ngModel">
          <option *ngFor="let data of data" [value]="data">{{data}}</option>
        </select>
</form>
# here #cities, #name is just template ref variable can be used or avoided in case you don't need to track control of model
```

Comment: Thanks for the time checking on this and the suggestion!